# Facebook OG:Type and share performance

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Does any one know if Facebook treats the `OG:type` of a page any differently when shared via the `share_open_graph` dialog?

For a while, we were using a custom `OG:type`, but noticed our traction slowly slipping (based on Facebook API impression data). Wondering if they simple treat website/article types with more authority when bubbling them into the feed?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think so, there shouldn't any difference in the impression tracking whether you share with the share dialog or any other channel.

Comment: @asarva thats interesting, we def. see a drop in impressions if we do a split  test between share_open_graph and the older feed (feed always wins).

curious, do you know if the og:type has any impact?  website/article versus a custom type?

Comment: Not really, og:tags is mainly used to serve the right metadata to the audience. It determines what your audience see in the link preview. The more interesting the metadata, the higher engagement you will have